# How to change the default image size for custom post type in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Inside Admin panel when we upload image for a specific post that image has default size medium(300 X 300). Instead of changing it every time from **Add Media > ATTACHMENT DISPLAY SETTINGS** while inserting into post or from **Edit > Image Details >DISPLAY SETTINGS** after inserting into post. How can we set the default image size to full/ original size or if it's full size then to medium/ thumbnail.

The main thing is to change the default image size setting. How do I do it?

Comment: Did you want to full image display on front-end post?

Comment: yes but without changing it every time from  ATTACHMENT DISPLAY SETTINGS & DISPLAY SETTINGS as mentioned in the question.

Comment: `the_post_thumbnail('full');` have you try this function to display post image ?

Answer (score 1):

```
function custom_image_size() {
    //set default for image size
    update_option('image_default_size', 'full' );
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'custom_image_size');
```

or simply

```
update_option('image_default_size', 'full' );
```

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/226915/how-to-set-the-default-embed-image-size