# WP update_option for medium_large thumbnail and make WP load these new size instead

Tags: wordpress, image-resizing

my theme uses the medium_large thumbnails (768x768) on mobiles and i want it to use 770x770 instead.

Tried it with update_option like this:

```
function change_ml_size() {
update_option( 'medium_large_size_w', 770 );
update_option( 'medium_large_size_h', 770 );
}

add_action('init', 'change_ml_size');
```

Unfortunately the theme is still trying to load the 768x768 size while the 770x770 thumbnails versions are available in the media library.

Any idea what i am missing here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the default image size for custom post type in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41542226/how-to-change-the-default-image-size-for-custom-post-type-in-wordpress)

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately not and the theme still pulls the 768x768 (responsive) image size when in some screen resolutions.